# Nodejs distinguishing http requests; multiple devices with same public IP

Tags: node.js, http, ip-address

Нello! I'm trying to represent client connections over http with node. Right now I have something like:

```
let names = [ 'john', 'margaret', 'thompson', /* ... tons more ... */ ];
let nextNameInd = 0;   

let clientsIndexedByIp = {};
let createNewClient = ip => {
  return {
    ip,
    name: names[nextNameInd++],
    numRequests: 0
  };
};

require('http').createServer((req, res) => {

  let ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

  // If this is a connection we've never seen before, create a client for it
  if (!clientsIndexedByIp.hasOwnProperty(ip)) {
    clientsIndexedByIp[ip] = createNewClient(ip);
  }

  let client = clientsIndexedByIp[ip];
  client.numRequests++;

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  res.end(JSON.stringify(client));

}).listen(80, '<my public ip>', 511);
```

I run this code on some remote server and it works fine; I can query that server and get the expected response. But I have an issue: my laptop and my smartphone are both connected to the same wifi; if I query that server from both my laptop and smartphone the server thinks that both devices have the same IP address and it only creates one "client" object for the both of them.

E.g. the "name" parameter of the response is the same for each.

Checking whatsmyip.org on both my laptop and smartphone shows me the same IP address - this surprised me, as my understanding of IPs turned out to be wrong. Until this point I thought all devices had a unique IP.

I want different devices to become associated with different clients, even when two devices are on the same wifi network. I assume that the data I'm using to disambiguate devices, their request IP alone (`req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress`), is insufficient.

How can I differentiate between multiple devices connected to the same router? Is there some extra bit of data in the `req` object which allows for this?

Or is it just a case of network misconfiguration that both my laptop and smartphone have the same IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest solution seems to be to use cookies(unique cookie for each user, guid maybe?). When the request comes in check if the cookie exists, if not create a unique id and place it to the cookies and send it back and also assign it to your client object.

Comment: This isn't a Node issue, this is a "this is how the web works" issue. Instead of using IP, you might consider fingerprinting. There are a few libs for this, search Node fingerprint

Comment: You've just discovered why so many websites have account signup/signin systems :) Trying to ID an individual device from only publicly available information when they connect is like trying to catch a single fish in the middle of an ocean: you could do it, but it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @Molda And then when the user clears their cookies (which, for some people, like me, happens as soon as they leave the site)? What then? Cookies are not a good measure of identity without a signin system.

Comment: Could MAC address help to differentiate devices?

Comment: @GershomMaes Mac addresses only exist in the immediate local network. If you look for a Mac address from a remote tcp connection you just get the one from the nearest switch or router.

Comment: Not being able to track users on the internet without their consent is actually a feature.

Comment: Aha thanks for the explanation! Makes sense. Looks like my server will be gaining a login feature :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the express-fingerprint module, this will work for most use cases, for example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var Fingerprint = require('express-fingerprint')

app.use(Fingerprint( { parameters:[
    Fingerprint.useragent,
    Fingerprint.geoip ]
}));

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("Client fingerprint hash: ", req.fingerprint.hash);
    res.send("Your client Id: " + req.fingerprint.hash);
});

app.listen(port);
```

Each client will have a unique hash you can use to identify them. It's worth understanding that this approach will have limitations and assigning a cookie to the client would work better for some use cases.

Comment: Isn't this a bit risky? This looks like it could confuse two separate devices which are sending the same User-Agent and geographic information - in a production environment that sounds like a liability.

Comment: Yes it is risky in a production environment. Since the hash is based on properties that may not be unique, it's not guaranteed to be unique for each client. If you really need a unique identity for clients you'll need to use another approach!

Comment: It looks like network architecture specifically prevents what I'm trying to accomplish! Any solution to my problem would only be partial, and since this is a partial solution it's roughly as good as any other answer! I'm accepting it.