# Nodejs - How do HTTP responses always hit the right device?

Tags: node.js, http, ip

Нello to all! A while ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176924/nodejs-distinguishing-http-requests-multiple-devices-with-same-public-ip). After helpful responses I learned that the web, by design, makes it impossible to directly differentiate devices connected to the same router.

So for example, the code below can never be 100% functional...

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {

    let uniqueDeviceId = getUniqueDeviceId(req);

}).listen(80, '<my public ip>', 511);
```

... because there's no way to implement `getUniqueDeviceId` in a guaranteed way. It can't just return `req.connection.remoteAddress`, as multiple devices could have the same address.

Given this, my question is: **How does `res.end(...)` always respond to the correct device??**

E.g. consider this simple server:

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {

    res.end(req.url);

}).listen(80, '{{my public ip}}', 511);
```

Take two different devices, connected to the same IP address. Each device uses its own url:

- Device 1 uses `http://{{my public ip}}/device1`
- Device 2 uses `http://{{my public ip}}/device2`

Now both these devices bombard their url with thousands of requests per second.

**In response, Device 1 will always get `/device1`, and Device 2 will always get `/device2`, even with this configuration that should lead to race conditions!**

Even though *I* can't determine a device's unique id directly, `res.end` will always correspond to the appropriate `req` - it will never blunder and send a response to some different `req`, even if that different `req` was received at almost exactly the same time, from the same IP address. To me this is proof that at some level, lower than Nodejs, unique device IDs can be determined.

**If this is correct, at what level of HTTP architecture do we get the guarantee that a response will always go back to its initial requester? And how is this implemented?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"To me this is proof that at some level, lower than Nodejs, unique device IDs can be determined"*

-- No, it's not the "unique device ID" that can be determined, but the unique "IP - Port" combination that is determined.

For example, in your case, Device 1 and Device 2 are hidden behind a router, which makes their IP identical (the IP of router) to your web server. However, although they have the same IP, their port are different.

For Device 1, from your Node.js web server's point of view, the socket (combination of SourceIP/Port - DestinationIP/Port) could be:

```
{{RouterIP}}:{{PortX}} - {{Node.js serverIP}}:{{Node.js serverPort}}
```

For Device 2, from your Node.js web server's point of view, the socket could be:

```
{{RouterIP}}:{{PortY}} - {{Node.js serverIP}}:{{Node.js serverPort}}
```

Thus, although Device 1 and Device 2 have the same IP, the HTTP response would be returned to corresponding port in router -- response for device 1 would be returned to PortX of router, while response for device 2 would be returned to PortY.

Then, inside the router, there is a mapping, such as:

```
{{PortX}} - {{Device 1's private IP}}:{{Device 1's Port}}
{{PortY}} - {{Device 2's private IP}}:{{Device 2's Port}}
```

So, the response returned to PortX of router woule be redirected to Device 1 (and its corresponding port), and the response returned to PortY would be redirected to Device 2.

This is called [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), and above description is just a very simple example.

*"what level of HTTP architecture do we get the guarantee that a response will always go back to its initial requester? And how is this implemented?"*

-- This has nothing to do with HTTP, it's belong to IP layer. The implementation happens in router. Web application developer don't need to do anything.

Comment: Wow, this is a great explanation. So it's the *router* that's doing the job of concealing its devices true socket values! It sends a "fake" socket value out into the world, and then remaps that value upon response to get it to the right device. Out of curiosity, is there a way in nodejs to see the "fake" socket value? And I assume that we're not just talking about my home router, but rather a remapping occurring at potentially every single hop?

Comment: @GershomMaes Yes, you can get the "fake" socket from HTTP request object in Node.js. Please check https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_request_socket

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses do "uniquely" identify devices. But even tho:

First off: http is on top of tcp/ip.
IP is a Standart of defining locations of devices in a Network. Devices get an IP from their router, and the device can send to a router to their own IP. (192.168.2.1:80(Router) -> 192.168.2.100:80(PC))

The router then sends stuff to the WWW, via your ISP.

Your public IP **-Request>** ISP **-Request>** TargetIP **-Answer>** ISP **-Answer>** You

(This all happens while the IP and Ports of the Package are kept in the Package which is wrapped inside other Packets. Also there are much more hops than these most of the time.)

---

Then there are ports: If you use an Port it will be locally blocked by the device. If there would not be Ports, TCP/IP would have those race conditions you mentioned as they would block each other.

---

The thing is this: You are not using different Ports or IP's. So whatever you are doing is just having one Server who handles both incoming Requests otherwise the second Server who tries to block the Port will not be able to as it's not TCP/IP conform.
You will not be able to have IP1:80/device1 and IP1:80/device2 running with 2 different Applications trying to block the Port 80.

So you are kind of right(that there would be discrepancies) but also very mislead by the thought of 2 Server being able to run of Port 80.

They way to handle the case you are talking about is the following:

Either

- Use Apache/Nginx/Nodejs and make a main Application(Router) to redirect Querys to the Server via Reverse Proxy and other kinds of *questing methods.
- Use different Ports

And for clarification: HTTP is the following:

- Pathing ( /this/is/a/path )
- Headers ( these you don't really see, but they contain cache hints, data types, and file handling on how files should be treated and as what and security )

What Servers do with HTTP is using the data that they get from the HTTP format. (which is simply just a specific layout of data in TCP) 
And use that to determine where to path/route the outcome.

Socket Handling as shaochuancs mentioned is Part of TCP and UDP, two low level Protocols. 
There are about 7 Layers in Networking. So this is only part of the whole story. If you are interested in learning more search for Network Layers specifically on Google. It's a good keyword to get more info about this Stuff.